# Why the argument is empty or null

Tags: windows, powershell

everyone
I'm a novice at Powershell.
My script gather Windows Event Viewer logs and export data to csv files. If the input is empty then is used the default values.
But it crashes:
"Export-Csv: Unable to validate argument for "Path" parameter. The argument is empty or NULL. Specify a non-empty, non-null argument and then run the command again."
Could explain to me why??

```
function exportLogs
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $exportFolder=(Read-Host -prompt "exportFolder"),
        $applicatiomLogs=(Read-Host -prompt "applicationLogs"),
        $systemLogs=(Read-Host -prompt "systemLogs"),
        $fromDate=(Read-Host -prompt "fromDate"),
        $eventTypes=(Read-Host -prompt "eventTypes")
    )

    $comp = $env:computername
    $now=Get-Date

    #check empty input and assign default values
    if (!$exportFolder) { [String]$exportFolder="D:\temp\" }
    if (!$applicationLogs) {
        $applicationLogs="True"
        [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($applicationLogs)    
    }
    if (!$systemLogs) {
        $systemLogs="True"
        [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($systemLogs)
    }
    if (!$fromDate) { [DateTime]$fromDate=$now.AddDays(-30) }
    if (!$eventtypes) { [String[]]$eventtypes=("Error", "Warning") }

    if ($applicationLogs)
    {
        $exportFile = $exportFolder + "applicationLogs_" + $now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv"
        $exportedLog = get-eventlog -ComputerName $comp -log "Application" -After $fromDate -EntryType $eventTypes
        exportCsv($exportedLog, $exportFile)
    }

    if ($systemLogs)
    {
        $exportFile = $exportFolder + "systemLogs_" + $now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".csv"
        $exportedLog = get-eventlog -ComputerName $comp -log "System" -After $fromDate -EntryType $eventTypes
        exportCsv($exportedLog, $exportFile)
    }
   
}

function exportCsv([String]$exportedLog, [String]$exportFile)
    {
        $el_sorted = $exportedLog | Sort-Object TimeGenerated
        Write-Host Exporting to $exportFile
        $el_sorted|Select MachineName, TimeGenerated, EntryType, Source, Message | Export-CSV $exportFile -NoTypeInfo
    }
```

Comment: Functions are called using syntax `FunctionName -Parameter1 Value1 -Parameter2 Value2`. They don't use method syntax `functionName(param1,param2)`. Try `exportCsv $exportedLog $exportFile`.

Comment: The somewhat inconsistent function call syntax can be confusing at the beginning. Native PowerShell functions (often called cmdlets) are called as @AdminOfThings has written, without parenthesis around the arguments. Contrary, when calling "low-level" .NET functions (like `Date.AddDays`), you must enclose arguments in parenthesis. As a shortcut you can remember to use the latter only when a function is called with dot "." or double colon "::" syntax.

Comment: Your function naming is not valid i.e., exportCsv. See the PS docs. The practice is Verb-Noun New-LogExport, as an example. Never use reserved words, names, default PowerShell objects, i.e., exportCsv is far too close to Export-Csv, in your naming. If you do, you just cause yourself unneeded issues. Functions must be loaded before they are called. that exportCsv is at the end and needs to be at the to or at minimum, before anything that calls it

Answer (score 0):

Try this refactor... (run on the default Windows Sandbox on Win10)

```
function New-LogExport
{
    Param
    (
        [String]$exportedLog, 
        [String]$exportFile
    )

    $el_sorted = $exportedLog | 
    Sort-Object TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "Exporting to $exportFile"
    
    $el_sorted | 
    Select-Object MachineName, 
    TimeGenerated, 
    EntryType, 
    Source, 
    Message | 
    Export-Csv -Path $exportFile -NoTypeInfo
}

function Start-ExportLogs
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        $exportFolder    = (Read-Host -prompt 'exportFolder'),
        $applicatiomLogs = (Read-Host -prompt 'applicationLogs'),
        $systemLogs      = (Read-Host -prompt 'systemLogs'),
        $fromDate        = (Read-Host -prompt 'fromDate'),
        $eventTypes      = (Read-Host -prompt 'eventTypes')
    )

    $comp = $env:computername
    $now  = Get-Date

    if (!$exportFolder) 
    {[String]$exportFolder = 'C:\temp'}

    if (!$applicationLogs) 
    {
        $applicationLogs = 'True'
        [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($applicationLogs)    
    }

    if (!$systemLogs)
    {
        $systemLogs = 'True'
        [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($systemLogs)
    }

    if (!$fromDate)
    {[DateTime]$fromDate = $now.AddDays(-30)}

    if (!$eventtypes)
    {[String[]]$eventtypes = ('Error', 'Warning')}

    if ($applicationLogs)
    {
        $exportFile = "$exportFolder\applicationLogs_$($now.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')).csv"

        $getEventLogSplat = @{
            ComputerName  = $comp
            LogName       = 'Application'
            EntryType     = $eventTypes
            After         = $fromDate
        }
        $exportedLog      = Get-EventLog @getEventLogSplat
        New-LogExport -exportedLog $exportedLog, -exportFile $exportFile
    }

    if ($systemLogs)
    {
        $exportFile = "$exportFolder\systemLogs_$($now.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')).csv"

        $getEventLogSplat = @{
            ComputerName  = $comp
            LogName       = 'System'
            EntryType     = $eventTypes
            After         = $fromDate
        }
        $exportedLog      = Get-EventLog @getEventLogSplat
    }
    New-LogExport -exportedLog $exportedLog -exportFile $exportFile
}

# Results
<#
exportFolder: 
applicationLogs: 
systemLogs: 
fromDate: 
eventTypes: 
True
True
Exporting to C:\temp\applicationLogs_20210120143659.csv
Exporting to C:\temp\systemLogs_20210120143659.csv
#>
```